# Input values summation and multiplication in one form

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I want to build a live javascript form to calculate prices.
There is 4 boxes:

```
<input type="text" id="hours" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="cars" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="1" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="2" oninput="calculate()">
```

The "1" and "2" box values are summation and multiplication with "cars" and "hours".

For example: 20 + 30 * 2 * 2

I tried it with this but it is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
        var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
            var myBox4 = document.getElementById('box4').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult = (myBox1+myBox2)*myBox3*myBox4;
        result.value = myResult;

    }


</script>
```

Comment: i can see error in element selector

Comment: Meh, as long as you only have these inputs you can also do something as simple and maintanable as that: http://jsfiddle.net/ezpjkexv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `value` property returns [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) and in this case `+` sign concatenates them. You need to convert your values to Integers, for example using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function:

```
var myResult = (parseInt( myBox2, 10 )+parseInt( myBox2, 10 ))*parseInt( myBox3, 10 )*parseInt( myBox4, 10 );
```

Also seems like your `id` attributes not equal to what you get in JS. Should be:

```
<input type="text" id="box1" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="box2" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="box3" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="box4" oninput="calculate()">
```

Working example:

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
  var myBox4 = document.getElementById('box4').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
  var myResult = (parseInt( myBox2, 10 )+parseInt( myBox2, 10 ))*parseInt( myBox3, 10 )*parseInt( myBox4, 10 );
  result.value = myResult;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box1" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="box2" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="box3" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="box4" oninput="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="result">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like Antyrat mentioned, you are not parsing the input which will be one reason and the second is you might get the null if there is no other input.
so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
        var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
        var myBox4 = document.getElementById('box4').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult;
        if(myBox1.length != 0 && myBox2.length != 0 && myBox3.length != 0 && myBox4.length != 0){
           myResult = (parseInt( myBox2, 10 )+parseInt( myBox2, 10 ))*parseInt( myBox3, 10 )*parseInt( myBox4, 10 );
       }else{
           myResult = 0;
        }

        result.value = myResult;

    }


</script>
```